# Rendering Bootstrap modal on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am trying to render a popup login window using Bootstrap modal. But it is not rendering on the same page it was rendering on the new page.

This is my code:

```
<%= link_to "view", signin_path, :id => 'login', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#loginModal' %>
```

I was trying to render this on  this page `http://localhost:3000/` But when I click on  my button "view" it was going to new url and start rendering   `http://localhost:3000/signin`

So how can I render on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
<%= link_to "view", "#loginModal", :id => 'login', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#loginModal' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should look something like this:

`<%= link_to "view", "#loginModal", data: { toggle: 'modal' }, %>`